# PHP cURL takes too long to load

Tags: php, curl, request

I have issue with cURL request from live server. I already seen this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733922/curl-takes-too-long-to-load) but not getting that solution.

Try to request local URL than its takes 562ms.

But the same code take 1.1 min from live URL.

below are the `curl_getinfo($cSession)` details :

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://***.***.**.**
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 62.261039
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000148
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 
    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
)
```

below I'm using code :

```
$cSession = curl_init();
//step2

curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_URL,"$url");
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');

//step3
$result=curl_exec($cSession);
$cinfo = curl_getinfo($cSession);

//step4
curl_close($cSession);

//step5, result of curl
// echo $result;

print_r($cinfo);
```

Can anyone please help me, where I'm failed.

Comment: generally, you should not force gzip. first off, if curl wasn't compiled with gzip enabled, and the server chose to use gzip, you'll get a corrupted download. second, if, in the future, a better algorithm is built into curl, it wont be used, and if the server supports DEFLATE but not gzip (DEFLATE is often built in), your download will be slower. just give an empty string to CURLOPT_ENCODING, and curl will list all supported encodings and the server will choose what it thinks fits best. only in edge case optimization scenarios, where you disagree with the server, you may want to force gzip

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
```

Try to use

```
curl_setopt($cSession, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```